# Convert Scala class (Not case class) to json

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to convert Scala case classes to JSON string. I had tried using frameworks like lift framework, but it converts case classes, not classes. How do I achieve the same for Scala class?

Comment: please do a try with Gson, Json4s, spary-json libraries. also please share your code snippet which you are trying

Comment: Might be worth to refactor your code so that the part you need to serialize can become a case class. With a case class, every Scala JSON library can automatically derive reads/writes.

Comment: Hi, Ani! Could you, please, give an example of your non-case classes that need to be serialize with an expected JSON samples?

Answer (score 3):

Try [`circe`](https://github.com/circe/circe).

Running an [example](https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html) from their website, in the scala console:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.4).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import io.circe.syntax._

val intsJson = List(1, 2, 3).asJson
println (intsJson)
import io.circe.syntax._

scala> 
scala> intsJson: io.circe.Json =
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]

scala> [
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

Another [example](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html) showing encoding with a real class:

```
scala> import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder

class Foo(val name: String, val size: Double)
implicit def encodeFoo: Encoder[Foo]= deriveEncoder

new Foo("foobar", 42.0).asJson

import io.circe.syntax._

scala> import io.circe.Encoder

scala> import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder

scala> 
scala> defined class Foo

scala> encodeFoo: io.circe.Encoder[Foo]

scala> 
scala> res0: io.circe.Json =
{
  "name" : "foobar",
  "size" : 42.0
}
```

I like circe simply because of the flexibility.

See [`awesome-scala` json](https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala#json) list for more options.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much every JSON library has a way to convert between JSON and native objects including [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/), which I recommend, [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJson), [Jackson](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html) and more.

[This article](https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/) gives you a tour of many libraries so you can pick one that suits your needs.

I notice your question explicitly says "not case class". In this scenario, the difficulty is having a constructor or access to private values of that class that represent its internal state. In this scenario, play-json uses Reads/Writes typeclasses that would allow you to expose or perform those specific mappings yourself. However it would be equally simply to write a getJson function on your custom (non-case) class and return whatever the library wants itself. My understanding is that none of the libraries can serialise the class to json the same way java's underlying serialisers can in a meaningful way as non-case classes likely don't expose the hidden type and name fields these libraries use. I could be wrong though.